# Are there little to no Explosive sniper rifles that are Rare / Blue or below?

Tags: borderlands-the-pre-sequel

Are there little to no Explosive sniper rifles that are Rare / Blue or below?

I have all the DLC, so I could try for a [Omni-Cannon](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Omni-Cannon), which is a Legendary that has a hidden Explosive trait... Assuming they spawn at LV 13...

I've managed to get almost every element for my sniper rifles, Pyro, Cryo, Electro, and Corrosive. I'm just missing Explosive.

Am I blind and somehow skipping over them in my vendors, or do they basically not exist?